# Parse json data with html content in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

In api sometime due to some error on server side app is getting html content with response. Api was executed properly but due to html content app is not able to parse response and shows error message. This same thing work fine in android because somehow android parser ignore html content and only prase json response. Same way I want to perform json parsing in objetive-C.

Below is content which is coming in api response.

```
 <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression in E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\common.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>261072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0117</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1264824</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>ExecutiveClass->executeQuery(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php<b>:</b>27</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0117</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1264928</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/oci_execute' target='_new'>oci_execute</a>
(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\common.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\common.php<b>:</b>6</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\common.php on line <i>8</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>261072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0117</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1264824</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>ExecutiveClass->executeQuery(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Delete_Dm_Group_Users.php<b>:</b>27</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0143</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1265656</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/oci_fetch_array' target='_new'>oci_fetch_array</a>
(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\GRABBER16\common.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\common.php<b>:</b>8</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"STATUS":"1","MESSAGE":"No Users Found!","DATA":[]}
```

Below is code which I am using to parse data in application

```
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
```

But this response data always give error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and 
option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with 
array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Is there any way to ignore this error and parse data with json content.

Comment: easy way out would be to use regular expression and get rid of all the html content before using NSJSONSerialization : data ,  for your case it would just be git rid of data until you find  first occurence of { or last occurence of >

Comment: @SouravSachdeva Yes you are correct at some point. getting rid of all the html content solve my problem but execution which you told will never work as some or the html contect having { } value which create isseu.  like you can see in question {main} there inside html.

Comment: "somehow android parser ignore html content " Is it true? Can this be reproduced on Android with THAT sample response? Because I'm wondering if that's because you are not forgetting an header or another param in your request.